# Renewal Process with Poisson lifetimes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, renewal-processes

I'm given the following question;

> Consider a renewal process for which the lifetimes X1, X2, · · · are
>   discrete r.v. having the Poisson distribution with mean λ.

And then asked to find the distribution of the Waiting time $W_k$ and P(N(t) = k),
using the standard definitions of

\begin{align}
& W_k = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i \\
and\\
&N(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb{I}\{{W_k \leq t}\}
\end{align}

Unfortunately, I don't quite understand what is being asked.  My understanding of a standard renewal process is that each $X_i$ exists for a certain period of time before failing, and then the next $X_i$ begins.  But in this case, I don't see how a sequence of Poisson random variables satisfies this.  I think once I actually understand the framing of the question I will be fine, so any assistance on what the question means would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it means that $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. Poisson random variables (integer valued).  It is weird to use these as inter-arrival times of a renewal process because it means some renewal durations can have size 0. But anyway, it seems $W_k$ is just the sum of $k$ i.i.d. variables, and $\{N(t)<k\} = \{W_k>t\}$.

Comment: For example, if the $X_i$ were $4,1,0,0,2,1,1,3,2,\ldots$ then the $W_k$ would be $4,5,5,5,7,8,9,12,14,\ldots$ and the $N(t)$ would be $0,0,0,1,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,8,\ldots$ (for positive integers $i,k,t$)

Comment: @Michael So if thats the case, then how do I calculate $W_k$ ?

Comment: Pablo: The distribution of the sum of $k$ i.i.d. Poisson distributed random variables with parameter $\lambda$  is a Poisson distributed random variable with parameter $k\lambda$.  That is the easy part of the question

Comment: @Henry, yes of course, thank you very much!!